# Display Confirmation bootstrap Modal when ModelState is valid using an ajax POST from Razor View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I have a scenario where I need to display a confirmation modal after the primary model has been validated on the server - using data annotations , but I want to actual commit to the DB to happen in the confirmation modal and not the main razor view:

Every thing works as expected except that I cannot wrap my head around how I display the confirmation partial view in a modal. I get redirected to the partial view alright but I just need it in a modal:

See pseudocode below:

`C# - actions`

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ConfirmUser()
{
    //Get TempData model here:
    return PartialView(model);
}


[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ConfirmUser(ConfirmUser usermodel)
{
   //UserService.ConfirmUser(usermodel)
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddNewUser(UserModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Some TempData logic here:

        return RedirectToAction("ConfirmUser");

    }
    return View(UserModel);
}
```

`Js -in Razor View`

```
      $("#add-new-User-form").submit(function (e) {

       e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        $.post($form.attr("action"),
 $form.serialize())
.done(function(dt, status, req)
        {

           if ($form.valid()) {

                $('#add-job-container').html(dt); //container
                $('#add-job-modal').modal('show'); //modal

            } else
            {
                //???

            }
         

        })

     });
```

the `$form.valid()` works but is only client side. I have also tried using `ViewData.ModelState.IsValid` on the view to no avail.
I assume I'd need to be returning Json objects from the actions and render the form on that basis ?

Comment: Have you not looked into returning some JSON from the server side code. e.g. return Json(new { success = true, message = ""}). Then on your client side you can do a check to see if the json returned success == true - if it is true, open your confirm user modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.If you want to display confirmation modal, you cannot use `RedirectToAction` in the backend, because ajax cannot handle redirect operation from backend.

2.**You cannot access the `ModelState` in client side**, it only works in server side.

I saw you return current view with model(`return View(UserModel);`) when `ModelState` is **invalid**. **Without ajax** this code is used to **display the form you filled and the error message**. Actually, by using ajax **in your scenario** it will always maintain the filled form and display error message.

If you just want to display the view with model data and error message, I suggest you return `BadRequest` in backend. Then it will get into the `ajax.error` function and no need judge `$form.valid()`.

A whole working demo you could follow:

**Model:**

```
public class UserModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

AddNewUser.cshtml

```
@model UserModel
<form asp-action="AddNewUser" id="add-new-User-form">
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input asp-for="Name" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
         <label>Email</label>
         <input asp-for="Email" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit"  value="ADD" />
</form>


<div class="modal fade" id="add-job-modal" tabindex="-1"  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        @*<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">  bootstrap version 4.x*@
        <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"="modal" aria-label="Close"> @*bootstrap version 5.x*@

          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="add-job-container">
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@section Scripts
{ 
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#add-new-User-form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this);
            $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize())
                .done(function(dt, status, req)
                {
                    $('#add-job-container').html(dt); //container
                    $('#add-job-modal').modal('show'); //modal       
                })
                .fail(function(res){
                    //ModelState is invalid 
                    //do your stuff..
                    alert(res.statusText);
                })
         });
     </script>
}
```

ConfirmUser.cshtml

```
@model UserModel
<h1>Confirm User</h1>
@Model.Name
@Model.Email
```

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult AddNewUser()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddNewUser(UserModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Some TempData logic here:
        return PartialView("ConfirmUser",model);
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```

**Result:**

[image]